# Can the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(-n^2 \pi^2 t)}}{n^2 \pi^2}$ be simplified?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following infinite sum:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(-n^2 \pi^2 t)}}{n^2 \pi^2}
$$

for $t \ge 0$ the sum always converges. Is it possible to write the convergent solution analytically as a function of $t$?

Comment: If we had such a formula $F(t)$, then $g(x)=\pi^2 F(-\pi^{-2}\log x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{n^2}$, and so $1+2xg'(x)$ would be an explicit formula for $\vartheta_3(0,x)$, which we do not really have. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.01589.pdf) might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Without the $1/n^2$ its some elliptic Theta function.

By its smoothness for $t>0$, its the integral of a Theta.

Contour integrals of elliptic functions are complex monsters of Riemann surfaces in a lattice of poles.

On the other hand,  the elliptic Thetas are solutions of the diffusion PDE, in this case it can be completed as

$$f(t,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{- t \ \pi^2 \ n^2 + i \ n \pi \ x)}} { (n \pi)^2}$$

as a solution to the diffusion equation $\partial_t =\Delta_x$ on the circle with a strange start condition

```
      Assuming[t > 0, 
   Limit[Sum[ Exp[-(n  \[Pi]^2 t + I n \[Pi] x] 1/(n \[Pi])^2, 
            { n, 1, \[Infinity]}],
     t -> 0]]

    PolyLog[2,E^(I \[Pi] x)]/\[Pi]^2
```

Comment: That is unfortunate that there is no analytical solution, but thank you for the explanation.